# How should I best extract "all unique data" from six 45 GB .7z files?

Tags: windows-10, backup, file-management, 7-zip, winmerge

I have just gone through the exhausting process of loading all my "gold backup" storage devices into my computer and, gradually, 7-zipped them and deleted the actual directory trees which are now inside the .7z archives. I deleted them because I don't have enough space to keep them all extracted at once.

So, now I have 6 x 45 GB .7z archives, each containing "basically" the same directory tree, but with potentially a number of unique sub-dirs or sub-sub-dirs or individual files.

I am trying to make a new "base gold backup" by making a new ~45 GB directory tree which represents all the files (and the latest versions, if there are such differences as well) found inside all these six archives.

When I try to compare two of them against each other, while WinMerge supports 7z unpacking, it gets errors related to "too long file paths" which is that stupid, inexplicable NTFS limitation which is being exhausted because the temp directory makes the full path too long. But I only mention this to show that I have tried *something*, but truly I cannot think of a "proper" way of accomplishing this task. Hopefully, some really smart people can give me clever ideas.

If possible, I would want to avoid using any extra software, because I don't trust such things anymore. I *am* able to script things to a certain degree (in PHP CLI), but it feels like there should exist a more "ready" and rock-solid way as this must be a common situation.

Update: It's the next day and only 10 people/bots have read this. It's never going to get answered or even commented on, is it?

Comment: It's the next day and many of the people who read/answer/comment are _just waking up_ at this time.

Comment: A possible approach is to parse the output from running `7z l archive.7z` to collect all filenames & their Date/Time entries. That would give you enough data to select the newest copies of each file.